# Highest power of prime dividing a number with PARI/GP

Tags: pari-gp

How do I find the highest power of a given prime `p` dividing a number `N` with PARI/GP?

E. g. if we have `p = 7` and `N = 3087` we get `e = 3` with `p^e | N` but `p^(e+1)` not dividing `N`.

I want to avoid a full factorization of the number `N`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `valuation` command, like so:

```
valuation(3087, 7)
```

This does not compute the factorization of the number.

Alternately, you could write your own function:

```
val(n, p)=
{
  if(n==0, return(+oo));
  my(e);
  while(n%p==0,
    n /= p;
    e++
  );
  e;
}
```